# Comparing stored date value to the current date of the computer

Tags: php, mysql

I am hopelessly stuck on this process and tried every approach I know to get the result I want. (I'm new to PHP and MySQL and this is my 3rd query regarding the same project)

What I really hope to do is update a specific field in an existing row that only **contains the same date**.

I have a table named **time_logs** with fields and records:

**user_ID | username | date_added | Time_In | Time_Out**
       1
            user1
      2014-05-13
     1:15
           1:30
       2
            user2
      2014-05-13
     1:15
           1:30

The Time_In and Time_Out are working perfectly well.

**user_ID | username | date_added | Time_In | Time_Out**
       1
            user1
      2014-05-13
     1:15
           1:45
       1
            user1
      **2014-05-14**
     1:30
           0:00

The Time_Out field will not have any record unless they have clicked on the "Time Out" button. The problem is, the Time_Out record for the same user, regardless of the date are being changed as well:

**user_ID | username | date_added | Time_In | Time_Out**
       1
            user1
      2014-05-13
     1:15
           2:00(should still be 1:30, different date)
       1
            user1
      **2014-05-14**
     1:30
           2:00

What I am hoping to accomplish is to compare the record on the date_added with the current date of the server. Something like this:
    if(record_of_date_in_the_database is == current_date)
      Record will not be stored
    else
      Proceed with the insertion of new Time_Out value

Is this possible? Hoping someone would teach me how to accomplish this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the query you run after clicking on "time out"?

Comment: $query = "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = '" . $time_added . "' WHERE username = '" . $user . "';";

Comment: you need another condition in WHERE: ... AND date_added = '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'";

Comment: I think I got it there. Thank you, @lulco. I just added what you've said.

Comment: When you fix this, I have another question: What if some user clicks on "time out" and then he will come back (in the same day)? Do you want to create another row in the table time_logs or you will set field Time_Out to default value 0:00?

Comment: Come back in the same day, you mean click on "Time In" again on the same day? My Time_Out button query does not work if it cannot find any record of the user that is logged in on my time_logs table.

Comment: Yes, I mean click on "time in" on the same day.

Comment: It will create a new record for the second Time_In

Comment: OK, so be careful when you will update time_out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run a query that looks something like this:

```
UPDATE time_logs 
SET time_out = CURTIME() 
WHERE user_id = $user_id 
    AND date_added = CURDATE()
```

Notes:

`$user_id` is the id of the user.

[**CURTIME()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time) gets the current time, like: '23:50:26'.

[**CURDATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) gets the current date, like: '2014-05-12'

You can also simply use PHP variables in place of `CURTIME()` and `CURDATE()`, if you wish. Just create them before running your query, and use them in place of the MySQL date/time functions.

Example:

```
$current_time = date("H:i");
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
```

For more information on formatting, read the docs on [**date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I got the idea from here and just added AND date_added = '$date_added' to my Update query. Thank you!